# What is the equivalent of this Python code in Hasekell?

Tags: python, haskell

I try to make the below Haskell code equal to the Python code, but it doesn't work and i can't spot the error? Can somebody spot the error? The Python output is what i want

```
def balanceList(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    if length<3:
        return lst
    else:
        middle=length//2
        return [lst[middle]] + balance(lst[middle+1:] + balance(lst[:middle]))

print( balanceList(list(range(1,10))) )
# [5, 3, 8, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 1]
```

```hs
balanceList :: [a] -> [a]
balanceList lst
  | len < 3 = lst
  | otherwise = [lst !! middle] ++ balanceList (drop (middle+1) lst) ++ balanceList (take (middle) lst) 
    where len = length lst; middle = len `div` 2

-- >>> balanceList [1..9]
-- [5,8,9,6,7,3,4,1,2]
```

Comment: Are you sure the Python version is correct? You write `balance(lst[middle+1:] + balance(lst[:middle]))`, but `balance(lst[middle+1:]) + balance(lst[:middle])` seems like a much more natural thing to want.

Comment: Don't worry about the sense. But yes, the Parenthese where the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the parenthesis:

```
balanceList :: [a] -> [a]
balanceList lst
  | len < 3 = lst
  | otherwise = [lst !! middle] ++ balanceList (drop (middle+1) lst ++ balanceList (take (middle) lst))
    where len = length lst
          middle = len `div` 2
```

Here we thus balance the first part, append the last part and balance it again. But it is unclear if that was the intention in Python.

But using `length` is not very "Haskell-ish". You can split the list in three through recursion:

```
splitMiddle :: [a] -> ([a], a, [a])
splitMiddle ls = go ls ls
  where go [] (x:xs) = ([], x, xs)
        go [_] ~(x:xs) = ([], x, xs)
        go (_:_:ys) ~(x:xs) = let ~(b, m, a) = go ys xs in (x:b, m, a)
```

or with a `NonEmpty`:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty(NonEmpty((:|)))

splitMiddle :: NonEmpty a -> ([a], a, [a])
splitMiddle (x :| xs) = go (x:xs) x xs
  where go [] x xs = ([], x, xs)
        go [_] x xs = ([], x, xs)
        go (_:_:ys) x ~(x1:xs) = let ~(b, m, a) = go ys x1 xs in (x:b, m, a)
```

Then we can use this to split and merge:

```
balanceList :: [a] -> [a]
balanceList lst@(_:_:_:_) = m : balanceList (a ++ balanceList b)
  where (b, m, a) = splitMiddle lst
balanceList lst = lst
```

Comment: Not sure I prefer `splitMiddle` over `length`+`splitAt`, especially since it's not total.

Comment: Yes the parentheses! How bad i didn't saw that :(

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I think the `lst!!middle` is the problematic part. `splitMiddle` should probably work with a `NonEmpty` though.

Comment: Yeah, but then you also need to convert to `NonEmpty` in `balanceList`, it's rather awkward. I'd use ``balanceList lst = case splitAt (length lst`div`2) lst of {(l,m:r) -> ...}``